# Open print preview page in new tab in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, printing, print-preview

Is there any way to open print preview page in new tab in chrome.
I m trying to

```
    `<a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="window.print();">Print_This_Page</a>`
```

but it does not work.

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this with javascript by first opening the page in a new tab/window, set a timeout so it would have time to finish loading, and then called the print-function

```
var printPage = window.open(document.URL, '_blank');
setTimeout(printPage.print(), 5);
```